# Can I slightly rotate a 2D vector (UV Edge) to more closely reflect the corresponding 3d vector?

Tags: mathematics, geometry, uv-mapping

I'm trying to get the difference between the 3D angle of two connected edges and their corresponding angle in 2D (mesh to UV space).  I would like to slightly rotate the angle in 2D to closer match the angle in 3D.  How do I rotate the 2D vectors to reflect this change?

Here's my current approach to get the angles:
3D angles:

```
dot3D = vectorA.dot(vectorB);  //normalized vectors
angle3D = acos(dot3D);
```

2D angles:

```
dot2D = vectorA.dot(vectorB);  //normalized
angle2D = acos(dot2D);
```

Angle difference:

```
angleDiff = angle3D - angle2D;
```

Rotation:

```
vectorC = vectorA - vectorB;
float deltaX = vectorC.x * cos(angleDiff) - vectorC.y * sin(angleDiff);
float deltaY = vectorC.x * sin(angleDiff) + vectorC.y * cose(angleDiff);
vectorA.x += deltaX;
vectorA.y += deltaY;
```

Comment: I think you are close on this.  But a couple of things, I assume that what you are trying to do if I paraphrase is, that if the angle of the 3d vectors is say 45 degrees, and that if you found that in 2d space your UV angle was 40 degrees, you need to adjust the UV by 5 degrees to be no longer stretched or compressed and map uniformly across the triangle?

Comment: Yeah, I have it working pretty well.  The main problem was determining if I need to add or subtract the angle.  Determining if my face edges were flowing clockwise or not was a big part.  I ended up adding angle/2.0f to one vector and subtracting angle/2.0f from the other.

Comment: Ahhh ok!  So the way I work out the direction is based upon doing the cross product of the 2 vectors to give you the rotation axis.  Depending on order of the vectors you use, this will give you a rotation axis, you are right though, the winding on your triangle will determine this.  From memory, if you are consistent in your approach with the application of the vectors (for the cross product), then you should be able to consistently calculate whther the angle should be added or subtracted. I would have to look back on my own code when I have time to give you more detail.

Comment: To also add, my calculations, I ended up using Matrices.  Sharpdx Matrix (c#) allows you to pass in a rotation axis and an angle, which made the logic around working out if the angle was positive or negative much more simple to determine.